# Converting a method written in Python to Java

Tags: java, python, sequence

I have been taking courses for both Python and Java. I am trying to convert a function I wrote for the course in Python to Java.  My main problem is creating a list to manipulate as is in the Python function.

This is the function in Python:

```
def merge(line):
    """
    Function that merges a single row or column in 2048.
    """

    line_copy = line[:]
    line_len = len(line)

    # removes all zeros from the list copy
    for num in list(line_copy):
        if num == 0:
            line_copy.remove(num)

    # "merges" like tiles and removes the "merged" tile from the list
    for idx in range(len(list(line_copy))):
        if idx + 1 < len(line_copy):
            if line_copy[idx] == line_copy[idx+1]:
                line_copy[idx] *= 2
                line_copy.pop(idx+1)

    # appends the appropriate number of zeros to the back of the list if any
    while len(line_copy) < line_len:
        line_copy.append(0)


    return line_copy
```

This is where I have left off in Java. The program is incomplete because I wanted to start testing the code with a tester class using a main method.

```
public class Merge {
    public static List<Integer> merge2048(ArrayList<Integer> line) {
        List<Integer> lineCopy = new ArrayList<Integer>(line);
        List<Integer> zero = Arrays.asList(0);
        lineCopy.removeAll(zero);
        return lineCopy;
    }
}
```

This is the tester class. It is a jumbled mess. I am having difficulty grasping the concepts of what would be sequence types in Java.

```
public class mergeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] line1;
        line1 = new int[]{1, 0, 2, 0, 4};
        ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>(line1);
        Merge mergeTest = new Merge();
        mergeTest.merge2048(line1);

    }
}
```

This brings me to my question. Am I on the right track? At this point in reading the Java docs, I am entirely confused about the creation, reading, and manipulation of sequence types in Java.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should simplify your python function:

```
def merge(line):
    """
    Function that merges a single row or column in 2048.
    """
    result = []
    for num in line:
        if num:
            if result and result[-1] == num:
                result[-1] *= 2
            else:
                result.append(num)
    while len(result) < len(line):
        result.append(0)
    return result
```

Then rewriting is more simple:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> merge2048(ArrayList<Integer> line) {
   ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for (Intger num : line) {
      if (num != 0) {
         if(result.size()>0 && result.get(result.size()-1) == num) {
            result.set(result.size()-1, result.get(result.size()-1) * 2);
         } else {
            result.add(num);
         }
      }
   }
   while(result.size()<line.size()) {
       result.add(0);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Two lines in the python code were wrong indented. And `last` was a leftover of a previous version.